# Paused in debugger in chrome?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When debugging in chrome, the scripts are always paused in the debugger even if there are no break points set, and if the the pause is un-paused, it again pauses itself.

What can be done?

Comment: +1 You might also find this useful: [How-to-terminate-script-execution-when-debugging-in-Google-Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134723/how-to-terminate-script-execution-when-debugging-in-google-chrome#answer-29392465)

Comment: Try slowing the internet speed by throttling to "Slow 3G", by the time it clears the network tab, you can easily right click and copy the request you want as curl. Simple & gets my job done without any extension or anything. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

One possible cause, it that you've enabled the "pause on exceptions" (the little stop-sign shaped icon with the pause (||) symbol within in the lower left of the window).  Try clicking that back to the off/grey state (not red nor blue states) and reload the page.

[image]

Comment: sometimes you should know where to click.

Comment: @DavidJ I added a screenshot of the icon, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was beginning to frustrate me. I don't even remember clicking that button.

Comment: Pausing on exceptions is neither a problem (@Luja) nor an issue (@Bosworth99) or something to be frustrated about (@dminer). It is a very helpful feature in debugging. It only takes a couple of hours (or less depending on your experience) to view all the options in the devTools UI and get comfortable with them. Please invest this time! It will help you immensely in your day-to-day debugging routine.

Comment: @CodeVortex Just because something is useful, that doesn't stop it being problematic if it is doing something you don't want right now and you don't know how to stop it.

Comment: wow thanks @DavidJ I was wondering why I had to do this for every site for a couple of days now ><

Comment: it might be in the *Top Right*

Comment: I've discovered that some web pages contain JS which trigger the pause if the developer console is open. Frustrating! Apparently it's used to stop people being able to easily poke about with the scripts.

Answer (score 112):

In my case, I had the `Any XHR` flag set true on the `XHR Breakpoints` settings, accessible over the Sources tab within Chrome's dev tools.

[image: Any XHR Flag in Chrome Dev Tools]

Uncheck it for Chrome to work normally again.

Answer (score 60):

This can also cause the issue

Break Point icon at top right should be blue like this

[image]

Should not grey like this

[image]

Comment: This is misleading as it disables stopping at any breakpoints, not the one at pageload. So this prevents also the breakpoints you want. The actual issue is not the button at the top right, but the checked "Any XHR" box at the bottom left.

Comment: This is good when you need to access the Debug window while being able to select something on the page, but the page gets locked by the script.

Comment: @k0pernikus I have no idea what is causing this for me but using this answer helped. I don't have `Any XHR` enabled.

Answer (score 13):

If you navigate to Sources you can see the pause[image] button at the bottom of the DevTools.
Basically there are 3 possible pause option in DevTools while debugging js file,

- **Don't pause on exceptions([image]) :**

  The pause button will be in **grey** colour as if "Don't pause on exceptions" is active.
  [image]
- **Pause on all exceptions([image]) :**

  The pause button will be in **blue** colour as if "Pause on all exceptions" is active.
  [image]
- **Pause on uncaught exceptions([image]) :**

  The pause button will be in **purple** colour as if "Pause on uncaught exceptions" is active.
  [image]

In your case, if you don't want to pause, select Don't pause on exceptions. To select, toggle the pause button till it become **grey**[image].

Comment: THANK YOU!  You're the only one who answered this with a *CLEAR* indication of which is which.

Tooltips should be helpful, not confusing: when it's grey, and thus disabled, the tooltip says "Pause on Exceptions"... which tooltips for toggles were less idiotic ("Don't pause on exceptions. Click to toggle.")

Answer (score 12):

And there is some options below ,if you have checked some,when the condition is active,the breakpoint debugger also active

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can press <kbd>CTLR</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to activate or deactivate breackpoints.

This is the short solution.

Answer (score 9):

At the right upper corner second last icon (encircled red in attached image) is for activate/deactivate debugging. Click it to toggle debugging anytime.

[image: Chrome Debug console]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Yep.  I'm just learning chrome dev tools today, and found the same thing -- if the above fails, expand the area pictured here and look for breakpoints you may have set and forgotten.

Answer (score 7):

Click on the Settings icon and then click on the Restore defaults and reload button. This worked for me whereas the accepted answer didn't. [image: Google Chrome Restore Defaults and Reload]

Comment: I had the same experience, and felt like I was taking crazy pills: http://cl.ly/f4Jj

The "restore defaults" in settings fixed this for me. No idea what it was, but as it wasn't happening in Canary I knew it was something specific to Chrome's dev tools.

Answer (score 4):

Its really a bad experience. if the above answer didn't work for you try this.

Click on the Settings icon and then click on the Restore defaults and reload button.

Press 'F8' until its became normal.

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 3):

Really silly issue that I ran into that led me here with the debugger; command.: ["debugger;" has a watch set on it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnTqx.png)

It caused a page that just said debugger; to appear between every page load.

The way to disable it is to just right-click said Watch and click "Delete watch expression".

Answer (score 2):

Another user mentioned this in slight detail but I missed it until I came back here about 3 times over 2 days -

There is a section titled EventListener breakpoints that contains a list of other breakpoints that can be set.  It happens that I accidentally enabled one of them on DOM Mutation that was letting me know whenever anything to the DOM was overridden.  Unfortunately this led to me disabling a bunch of plug-ins and add-ons before I realized it was just my machine.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

For me this was due to a chrome extension, i turned off a few unwanted extensions and the message was gone.

Comment: Same for me, it was a random chrome extension. This should be upvoted higher. Huge headache to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go to Breakpoints in the chrome developer console, right click and remove breakpoints. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

[Threads > switch "Main" to "app"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZMXI.png)

In the "Threads" section I changed the context from "Main" > to "app". The "app" should have a blue arrow aside.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me. I had a breakpoint on subtree modifications on the body tag, and every time I removed the breakpoints, they would be back after I refreshed. I was so confused, and I even removed all DOM breakpoints, but the phantom body subtree modification breakpoint kept coming back. Eventually, I reloaded the cache, and they disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

no need to worried.
just click here and refresh your page.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome Debugger Pause Button -- *international hide & seek champion!*

Here is what it looks like in 2022:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

✅ Just make sure you have unchecked both of these:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was enabled Pasue on Caught Exceptions

Answer (score -1):

There was a syntax error in my `for` loop. This caused the pause error.