# Why chrome debugger does not working in this site?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Please head over to https://www.midasbuy.com/midasbuy/ot/shop/pubgm site,
if you try to debug or inspect it, it pauses the debugger.
is there any solution to fix this?
how is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paused in debugger in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833514/paused-in-debugger-in-chrome)

Comment: its called a *debugger jammer*, it's easily bypassable by local overrides but prevents noobs easy access to the dom for scraping etc

Comment: Doesn't even need local overrides. One only needs to clear the interval that runs the `debugger` code.

Comment: [Is it possible to avoid breaking on a debugger statement in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53970719)