# Chrome disabled javascript and doesn't allow to enable it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am not able to enable javascript in Chrome. Under Chrome javascript setting the default option for **"sites can use javascript"** is grayed out. Even if I add website manually under **"Allowed to use javascript"** the website is not loading, screenshot below.

This happened while I was trying to find a solution for another issue and followed solution from this page (the top answer), so I went to *Chrome Devtools > Sources* and clicked on the pause button since then the javascript has got disabled. [Paused in debugger in chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833514/paused-in-debugger-in-chrome)

Note: Javascript is working fine in other Chrome Profiles. The issue is with this particular Chrome Profile.

[image: javascript under chrome setting]

Answer (score 1):

Try right-clicking the "Sites can use Javascript" option, and inspect element:
[image: Exmple]

Then, remove the `disabled` or `disabled=""` attribute from whatever element the console brings you to.

The option should be enabled. Click it and try reloading your site again.

If this doesn't work, you can try reporting any problems for whatever chrome has (I use Mozilla Firefox and I know they have a help center).

Or try re-installing the browser, because some files may be corrupt (don't worry, if you have an account you can sign-in after the reinstallation and everything should be synced).

Comment: Disable under Inspect element wasn't working. I had to remove the chrome profile. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @FaizSheikh No problem! Hope everything works well.